# Calculate the length of $\gamma(t)=(t,t), t \in [-1,-\frac{1}{2}]$ with the metric $g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ and compare with euclidean metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

> Consider the metric $g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^2=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y>0\}$.
>
> Calculate the length of the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,t), t \in [-1,-\frac{1}{2}]$ and compare with the length of the same curve with the euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I know that, in theory, the length of the curve is given by $$\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sqrt{g(\gamma',\gamma')}dt$$ where $\gamma'(t)=D_{\gamma_t}(\frac{d}{dt})$.

In practise I don't know how to proceed.

Also, I presume that the length of the given curve with respect to the euclidean metric is $$\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|\gamma'(t)\|dt = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}.$$

Am I making some confusion here? Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: $\gamma'(t) = (1,1)$ yes? Then $g(\gamma', \gamma') = (1^2 + 1^2)/t^2$.

Comment: So if $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$, then $g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))=\frac{\gamma_1'(t)^2+\gamma_2'(t)^2}{\gamma_2(t)}$ with this metric $g$?

Comment: The $y$-component  should be squared in the denominator.

Comment: Of course, thanks, but an I thinking correctly with the euclidean metric?

Comment: For $t\in [-1,-.5]$ your $\gamma(t)$ does not belong to the upper half plane $\mathbb{R}_+^2$.

Comment: @Mercy Yes, you are right, but I think I get the point, we could do this with $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2)$ as well. Thanks for remarking this.

Comment: I think you'd want $\gamma(t) = (t,-t)$ if we stick with the negative time domain. That $t^2$ would make the integration less trivial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say $g = \frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ is to say $g = \frac{1}{y^2} (dx \otimes dx+dy \otimes dy)$. Then $\gamma'(t) = \frac{d\gamma^1}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)}+\frac{d\gamma^2}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)}$ hence $$g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)) = \left(\frac{1}{y^2}(dx \otimes dx+dy \otimes dy)\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg{|}_{(t,t)}\right)$$
which gives
$$ g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t)) = \frac{2}{t^2}$$
hence $\sqrt{g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))}dt = \sqrt{2}dt/|t| = -\sqrt{2}dt/t$ (as $t<0$) finally, just integrate over $[-1,-1/2]$ to obtain $\sqrt{2}\ln(2)$. And, yes, I do think your Euclidean length is correct.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{2}\ln 2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \ln 4$ we see the length of the curve is shorter in the Euclidean metric.